# How to make printf to print a character buffer the same way as NSLog does?

Tags: c++, objective-c, formatting

I am using a cross-platform library with `printf()` function to dump data bytes to console. I noticed that for some reason bytes get translated into their decoded variants instead of dumping them "as is". But when I use `NSLog` function, the output is correct.

Here is a simplified code example from my unit test:

```
unsigned char *buff = new unsigned char[3]{ 0xff, 0xfe, 0x00};

NSLog(@"\n\n---%s---\n\n", buff);
printf("\n\n---%s---\n\n", buff);
```

It yields the following output:

```
2017-08-03 12:08:53.879 xctest[4725:44271]

---ˇ˛---


---\377\376---
```

As you see, NSLog treated bytes `0xff, 0xfe` "correctly" and wrote only two symbols `ˇ˛` but printf wrote `\377\376` instead.

**How do I make printf to print `ˇ˛` (or any other two symbols) in this case?**

I don't care about Unicode correctness; I just need printf to print only two symbols in this case instead of that `\x\y` string.

By the way, when I run the same `printf` code on Windows, it outputs only two characters instead of `\x\y`, so this issue might be *nix specific.

Comment: Perhaps `printf` doesn't know about any extended characters beyond the basic 7-bit ASCII? Perhaps you need to set the locale properly (do some searching for `setlocale`)?

Comment: I thought so, too, and I just tried `setLocale(LC_ALL` with "", "C", "en_US", "en_US.UTF-8" but no effect on `printf`. Not sure, which locale would help, if any.

Comment: I found that on Windows there is also `SetConsoleOutputCP` which affects the output format, but I can't find an equivalent for *nix.

Comment: I think the issue is less about Unix and more about macOS (which I assume is the target considering your use of Objective-C and `NSLog`).

Answer (score 1):

The `NSLog` output is the one which isn't dumping "as is" to the "console" (stderr in this case) - it is writing the four bytes `313 207 313 233` for the two bytes `377 376`.

`printf` is outputting the bytes `377 376` to the "console" (stdout in this case).

If you compile the code as a command line app and then in the Terminal pipe the output through `od -bc` you will see this.

So it is Xcode's pretty printing which is producing the `\377\376`.

If you want the "as is" bytes you could use `fprintf` to write to a file, or if you can't change the code you can use `dup(2)` etc. to capture the output sent to stdout.

Alternatively you could maybe pre-process your strings to replace non-printables with a single character.

HTH